# How to install Lan card driver using freebsd kernel

Tags: freebsd

I have bought Asus xg-c100c LAN Card. But freeBSD(TrueNas) not supporting. I have download driver files from manufacturer website. All files have .c Or .h extension. How to install it ?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because Questions about operating systems, their utilities, networking and hardware, are off topic here. [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). Please delete this and ask, instead, on https://unix.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is: if the card didn't specifically have a FreeBSD driver, you cannot use the one you downloaded.  It sounds like you downloaded a linux driver in source form, because I'm relatively sure your chipset has no FreeBSD driver.

There *was* the ability to use NDIS drivers back-in-the-day.  You're talking about the ASUS 10GE chipset, I believe.  There is not driver it (yet).

Your best bet is to get a cheap card and put it in a PCIe slot or get a USB3 ethernet (better than USB2 for 1GE) and use it.  Obviously, the USB solution won't be 10GE.